# Unresponsive show dialog window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am showing a modal dialog with my background worker, but it's becoming unresponsive when some long task is done on completed event of worker thread. Can someone tell me why it is happening and how I can fix this?

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var back = new BackgroundWorker();
    back.DoWork += delegate
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 100)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            i++;
        }
    };

    back.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
    {
        //running  along task on UI therad

        int i = 0;
            while (i < 10000)
            {

                int j = 0;
                while (j<10000)
                {

                    label.Content = i.ToString();
                    j++;
                }

                i++;
            }
        msgbox.Close();
    };

    back.RunWorkerAsync();

    msgbox.Title = "loading";
    msgbox.Owner = this;
    msgbox.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: `RunWorkerCompleted` gets executed in the UI thread and you're "sleepeing" it

Comment: Thread.Sleep is representing a long running task here for demonstration of problem.

Comment: therefore, that heavy operation is blocking your UI thread. I'd try to approach it using `async` and `await` rather than background workers

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* run any long-running method on the UI thread without blocking it. A single thread cannot both execute your while loop(s) and respond to user input simultaneously. This is impossible.

That's why you should execute any long-running method on a background, i.e. in the `DoWork` event handler in this case.

The `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler should only perform some quick UI related tasks, like for example updating a label or similar. Don't do anything heavy in there because then you *will* block the UI thread and your application *will* become unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

This part is executed in the UI thread:

```
    back.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
    {
        //running  UI therad

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 100)
        {

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            label.Content = i.ToString();
            i++;
        }

        msgbox.Close();
    };
```

When you call `Thread.Sleep(100);` you put the whole UI thread to sleep. Meaning, that your UI will sleep for 10 seconds.